# Symfony2 and Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, assetic

I created a Bundle in order to include Twitter Bootstap into my project. I'm aware, that there existing Bundles for that but I wan't to take control of it by myself. That means I don't want to install Less compiler and stuff like that.

The .js and .css file are applied well if I include them as follows into my template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{% javascripts
'@MyAssetBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
'@MyAssetBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets '@MyAssetBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I only struggle with including the appropriate fonts in order to use the glyphicons Bootstrap provides.

According to the css definitions the fonts are supposed to be available at ../fonts relative to the css-file. In fact I put them there. But Symfony2 resolves this relative urls into an absolute path and does not find a route for that.

How can I solve this? I really feel like I didn't get a important part of the Symfony2 concepts here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `cssrewrite` filter provided by Assetic to correct the paths within your CSS files.

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    'bundles/myassetbundle/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Make sure that you are using the `bundles/myassetbundle/...` notation instead of the `@MyAssetBundle` one.

Read the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter) about this matter.

Comment: I did. The URLs are rewritten to an new one. But it still does not work. Before the rewrite the URLs were like http://www.mysite.org/app_dev.php/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, after http://www.mysite.org/Resources/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff.

Comment: Can you post your `{% stylesheets %}` block?

Comment: I've updated the answer, check the path notation you are using.

Comment: I updated my question and included the css code. @albertedevigo: The way you proposed to include the css file didn't work at all. Means Symfony does not include any css anymore.

Comment: Well, that way is the correct one, see the docs. So it should work. Maybe you are not dumping your assets properly. Try to `cache:clear`, then `assets:install` and then `assetic:dump`. Check that after installing your assets everything is on its place under `web` directory.

Comment: Well `assetic:dump` did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

The answer from @albertedevigo is working just fine but there might be a case when you need to take an additional precaution:

**Make sure you have extracted the full bootstrap zip before moving its files in your web folder.**

I first only moved them from inside the ZIP and they would appear in green in my windows explorer and I could not access them. So make sure you unzip the folder first before moving its content and have the full access write on the files.